# What is the height of liquid risen when a solid cylinder is inserted into a tub of water?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-statics

**Problem**: In a cylindrical tub of area $A$ and height $H$, water is upto a level of $H/2$. A solid cylinder of length $L$ and area $A/5$ is inserted into the tub and it is floating vertically with $L/4$ portion immersed. What is the increase in water level?

**My Solution:**
Let us assume the new level to be $H'$ and conserved the volume of water.

$H/2.A = L/4.(A-A/5) + (H'-L/4).A$

from which I got $H' = H/2 + L/20$. Which is even matching with answer given in the book.

But in the solution given in the book author has taken a different approach which is what I want to understand.

**Author's Solution:** 
Let $x$ be the height of liquid risen above previous level (H/2).

Volume of water displaced by the cylinder ($= L/4.A/5)$ = $x.A$

Therefore, $x=L/20$ and new level of water is $H/2 + L/20$

I didn't understand how he equated volume of water displaced by the cylinder to $x.A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To appreciate that xA is indeed the volume of water displaced, redraw the figure with the immersed part of the cylinder moved to the bottom (just for ease of calculation of the volume of the displaced water). In this new picture the top layer of thickness(height) x contains the displaced water and has a volume of xA.[image]

By the way, your method is correct too. It has a typo on the LHS of the first equation (H should be replaced by H/2).

Comment: Aaah!! Now it makes sense. Corrected my typo.